# Import multiple csv using loop pattern in different subdirectories

Tags: r, loops, csv, variables

I am writing a script with BIDs file formatting (brain imaging data structure) for R.  I need to be able to use the general format with a portion of the path representing another variable:

```
subj=VARIABLE
t1s${subj}=read.csv("./sub-${subj}/ses-1/beh/*task-navon*")
```

This should work so that user can import subject numbers as we collect them and then use the script to read in that subject into a df.  I then will go forward to "wrangle" the data continuing to use $subj number to do things like add columns listing subj. numbers repeated the same number of times as the df length (printed from another function into a variable, etc).

example files for use in the script:

```
t1s10001=read.csv("./sub-10001/ses-1/beh/sub-10001_ses-1_task-navon_beh.csv")
t1s10002=read.csv("./sub-10002/ses-1/beh/sub-10002_ses-1_task-navon_beh.csv")
t1s10003=read.csv("./sub-10003/ses-1/beh/sub-10003_ses-1_task-navon_beh.csv")
```

Bonus:: if you know how to do this so that subj can have multiple inputs

ie:

```
insert subject numbers:
10001 10002 10003
```

So that $subj numbers are saved into $1 $2 $3 $4 spaces and automatically looped through the import process (and the rest of the script)

Comment: Look into `paste`, `sprintf`, or `glue::glue`. Perhaps use that with `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)`.

Comment: glue is interesting but it won't let me use any of the above within another variable name (that I can figure out) as I'm trying to do with t1s${subj}.  glue('t1s{subj}') prints the correct output but glue('t1s{subj}')= read.csv doesn't work.  If I put the entire line within glue, it prints the correct output but doesn't run the read.csv command.

Comment: `glue(...)=read.csv(...)` does not make any sense to me, I would expect something like `read.csv(glue_data(x, "./sub-{subj}/ses-1/beh/sub-{subj}-ses-1...csv"), ...)` (where `x` is something that defines your `subj`ect, et al).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `map` and then `split` to read in the CSV files and store them as data frames within a list.

```r
# test.csv files are saved within directories names 'sub1', 'sub2', etc.
d <- data.frame(filename=list.files(pattern = '.csv',full.names = T,recursive = T),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

         filename
1 ./sub1/test.csv
2 ./sub2/test.csv
3 ./sub3/test.csv

# read in CSV files and create subject ID var from filename
dd <- d %>% mutate(data=map(filename,~read_csv(.)),
                   subject=str_split(filename,'/',simplify = T)[,2])

# split dataframe to a list, with subject ID as the name of each element
setNames(split(dd,seq(nrow(dd))),dd$subject)

$sub1
         filename               data subject
1 ./sub1/test.csv this, is, my, data    sub1

$sub2
         filename               data subject
2 ./sub2/test.csv this, is, my, data    sub2

$sub3
         filename               data subject
3 ./sub3/test.csv this, is, my, data    sub3
```

Alternatively, if the CSV files that you are reading in all have the same format, you can `unnest()` the files to create one large data frame of all subjects.

```r
d %>% mutate(data=map(filename,~read_csv(.)),
                   subject=str_split(filename,'/',simplify = T)[,2]) %>% 
  unnest()
         filename subject    a  b  c    d
1 ./sub1/test.csv    sub1 this is my data
2 ./sub2/test.csv    sub2 this is my data
3 ./sub3/test.csv    sub3 this is my data
```

Comment: the top solution worked! I added one line to work with BIDs format if anyone else is doing so.  After the 'dd' variable, do ```ddd=dd %>% mutate(subject=str_split(subject,'-',simplify=T)[,2])``` and then set the files as ```files=setNames(split(ddd,seq(nrow(ddd))),ddd$subject)``` . Thank you!